# Url Helper ASP.NET MVC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm writing a js script that read a file JSON that contains all navigation menù links of my web application.
the menu tree is something like this:

```
1 - DASHBOARD - dashboard
2 - SETTINGS
    2.1 - GENERAL - settings/general
    2.2 - LAYOUT - settings/layout
3 - DATABASE
    3.1 - QUERY
       3.1.2 - EDITOR - database/query/editor
       3.1.3 - TEST - database/query/test
```

the menù is 3 levels nested link.

How can I write links in JSON file to avoid "`not found`" when e.g. in "`DASHBOARD`" and want to go to `SETTINGS > GENERAL`.

I don't want to use absolute path, my webapp will run in a virtual directory.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, I wolud suggest modifying your JSON response to include the base path your app is hosted on.

```
string basePath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"));
```

For example: `basePath + "database/query/editor"` instead of `database/query/editor`.

If you cannot modify the JSON response, you can get the base path your application is hosted on in a JavaScript variable from your MVC.

In your `_Layout.cshtml` file -- or whatever file that gets loaded every time your application is loaded -- set your base path that your application is running under in a JS variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.applicationBaseUrl = @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Content("~/"), true));
</script>
```

Now when you receive the JSON containing the URLs, concatenate them with your base path:

```
var queryEditorUrl = window.applicationBaseUrl + <the path from your JSON>
```

This way your URLs are independent of the virtual directory it is hosted on.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Url.Content("~/")` ([see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)) to get the absolute URL of your application. For example if you run your application in a virtual directory called `MyApp` and you have a page in `About/Me` you can use:

```
string url = Url.Content("~/About/Me"); // this will return '/MyApp/About/Me'
```